# My listview is not displaying its content

Tags: java, android

Here is the code for MainActivity
How to view listview products please suggest me as soon as possible

```
public class ProductList extends AppCompatActivity {
public static ArrayList<ItemProductList> values1=new ArrayList<ItemProductList>();
ListView list_productlist;
Context context = this;
public ItenProductAdapter mAdapter;
String category,name1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
    list_productlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_productlist);
    category=getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
    name1=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    loadJSON();
    mAdapter= new ItenProductAdapter(context,values1);
    list_productlist.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void loadJSON() {
    StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "http://arshinfosystems.co.in/demo/AoneRubber/productlist.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("cart");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jbjct = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            ItemProductList itemListModel = new ItemProductList();
                            itemListModel.thickness1 = jbjct.getString("thickness");
                            itemListModel.id1 = jbjct.getString("id");
                            itemListModel.price1 = jbjct.getString("price");
                            itemListModel.category1 = jbjct.getString("category");
                            itemListModel.name1=jbjct.getString("name");
                            itemListModel.sr_no=jbjct.getString("sr_no");
                            values1.add(itemListModel);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(ProductList.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("category", category);
            params.put("name", name1);
            return params;
        }
    };
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
  }
}
```

Here is the code for Adapter
How to view listview products please suggest me as soon as possible please guys

```
public class ItenProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public static ArrayList<ItemProductList> list1;
String idValues = "";
Context context;
public static Integer total;
Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
ViewHolder holder;

public ItenProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemProductList> list) {
    super();
    this.list1 = list;
    this.context = context;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_sr_no;
    TextView txt_thickness;
    TextView txt_rates;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, null);

        holder.txt_sr_no= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sr_no);
        holder.txt_thickness= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_thickness);
        holder.txt_rates= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_rates);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txt_sr_no.setText(list1.get(position).sr_no+")");
    holder.txt_thickness.setText(""+ list1.get(position).thickness1);
    holder.txt_rates.setText("RS "+list1.get(position).price1);




    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: set the adapter inside volley response

Comment: done but it is of no use

Comment: @Camahalan Royette I have an issue in my app that is the login and signup activity is not opening in kitkat version it is opening in higher version how to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code method getCount() returns 0. Change it to

```
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

BTW its better to extend ArrayAdapter.

Comment: I have an issue in my app that is the login and signup activity is not opening in kitkat version it is opening in higher version how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Your `getCount` function of your adapter always returns that is has no items

Change this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

to something like this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (list1 != null) {
        return list1.size();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("cart");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jbjct = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            ItemProductList itemListModel = new ItemProductList();
                            itemListModel.thickness1 = jbjct.getString("thickness");
                            itemListModel.id1 = jbjct.getString("id");
                            itemListModel.price1 = jbjct.getString("price");
                            itemListModel.category1 = jbjct.getString("category");
                            itemListModel.name1=jbjct.getString("name");
                            itemListModel.sr_no=jbjct.getString("sr_no");
                            values1.add(itemListModel);
                            }
                       mAdapter.setList(values1);
                       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       }
```

Adapter Class

```
public class ItenProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public static ArrayList<ItemProductList> list1;
String idValues = "";
Context context;
public static Integer total;
Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
ViewHolder holder;

public ItenProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemProductList> list) {
    super();
    this.list1 = list;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<ItemProductList> list){
    this.list1 = list;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list1.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_sr_no;
    TextView txt_thickness;
    TextView txt_rates;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, null);

        holder.txt_sr_no= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sr_no);
        holder.txt_thickness= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_thickness);
        holder.txt_rates= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_rates);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txt_sr_no.setText(list1.get(position).sr_no+")");
    holder.txt_thickness.setText(""+ list1.get(position).thickness1);
    holder.txt_rates.setText("RS "+list1.get(position).price1);




    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: so your problem is missing mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and  Adapter getCount() is alway return 0;

Comment: And that list1 is never updated... It gets set as an empty ArrayList...

Comment: Just move the notifyDataSetChanged into the setList method? You can then get legendary with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html

Comment: do you know what is your code problem? onResponse() get new Data. but  your mAdapter data(it mean list1) has nothing change. so your mAdapter item count is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 onCreate 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
    list_productlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_productlist);
    category=getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
    name1=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    loadJSON();

}
```

Then the onResponse

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("cart");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jbjct = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            ItemProductList itemListModel = new ItemProductList();
                            itemListModel.thickness1 = jbjct.getString("thickness");
                            itemListModel.id1 = jbjct.getString("id");
                            itemListModel.price1 = jbjct.getString("price");
                            itemListModel.category1 = jbjct.getString("category");
                            itemListModel.name1=jbjct.getString("name");
                            itemListModel.sr_no=jbjct.getString("sr_no");
                            values1.add(itemListModel);
                        }
                   //Check if list is empty or not
                    if(values1.size()>0){
                    mAdapter= new ItenProductAdapter(context,values1);
                   list_productlist.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can I make a couple edits? I always like to have an `updateData` method in my Adapters (then they call `notifyDataSetChanged`. This way you can also then `loadJson` later and update the page without needing to create a new Adapter

Comment: @quick learner I have an issue in my app that is the login and signup activity is not opening in kitkat version it is opening in higher version how to resolve it